# UICollectionView as a subview doesn't update constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I'm having an **autolayout** puzzle. Here's the description:

I have a `UITableViewCell` that has a "container view" which is a basic `UIView` and then `UICollectionView` is a subview of this container view.

```
UITableViewCell -> UIView -> UICollectionView
```

It's a bit simplified from the end goal which includes a little more views under the tableViewCell, but for the sake of the question it should be good enough.

Both `UIView` and `UICollectionView` have constraints in the following format:

`H:|[view]| and V:|[view]|` (e.g. take full size of the tableViewCell).

**For some reasons the constraints are not being updated after UICollectionView lays out it's cells.**

*Here's what works:*

1. If I replace `UICollectionView` with a `UILabel`, then it works fine (e.g. tableViewCell is properly dynamically sized depending on the label text).
2. If I remove the intermediate UIView (the container view) from the puzzle then again it all works fine (e.g. tableViewCell is properly dynamically sized depending on number of cells in UICollectionView).

*What doesn't work* is when I have UICollectionView added to the intermediate view like this: `UITableViewCell -> UIView -> UICollectionView`

**Any ideas how to solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not recommend use as subviews  other scrollable objects inside uitableview.

To achieve your goal:

1. Add equalWidth constaint for your UICollectionView (to uitableviewcell)
2. Add equalHeight constaint for your UICollectionView (to uitableviewcell)

Comment: Adding UICollectionView within UITableViewCell directly works fine. It's when I add an intermediate UIView into the view hierarchy, everything breaks.

Comment: Did you try adding height/width constraint from uicollectionview to your intermediate view?

Comment: Yes.. as as a work around for now I'm calculating number of rows in the collection view based on the content to show there. With the number of rows and having a default cell height I can set the height for the collection view via constraints programmatically.